# Require little help on setting url rewrite cond for url rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following rewrite rule.

```
RewriteRule    ^products/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$    products/prd_templates/index.php?url=$1    [NC,L]
```

..that rewrites the page url correctly. Pointing it from

```
mydomain.com/products/product-alias -> mydomain.com/products/index.php?url=product-alias
```

Now my problem is this.

When i go to

```
http://www.mydomain.com/products
```

My page seem to redirect to another page instead of loading my index.php in my products directory.

I think i need to set up some rewrite cond rule to prevent redirect of my products directory .

Wonder if there is anyone who could point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d